# Surprising numeric widening in Scala

Tags: scala

### Code

```
object Test {
        def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
                val x = 123456789L
                val y = 1.0F

                val a = x - (if (true) { x } else { y })
                val b = (if (true) { x } else { y }) - x
        }
}
```

---

### Result

Running this code, a is `-3.0: Float` and b is `0.0: Float`. (`x.toFloat` is `1.23456792E8: Float` because of precision loss.)

---

### Scala Specification

According to [Conditional Expressions](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#conditional-expressions) and [Weak Conformance](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#weak-conformance): the type of the `if` expression in both cases is `Float`. (`Float` is the weak least upper bound of `Long` (the type of the then-part) and `Float` (the type of the else part).)

As a result, we have `Long - Float` in the first case, and `Float - Long` in the second case.

In the first case, both operands are widened (?) to `Double` for the calculation and the result is narrowed to `Float` for assignment. In the second case, both operands are widened to `Float` only.

According to [Numeric Widening](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#numeric-widening), the expected type of `a` must be `Double` for both operands to be widened to `Double`. However, it is `Float`.

What is going on here? Are any other rules at play here? Is this a bug in the compiler? Please explain in detail and cite supporting evidence. Thank you.

---

### Bytecode

The observed behavior can be confirmed by looking at the generated bytecode:

```
$ javap -c 'Test$.class'
Compiled from "Test.sc"
public final class Test$ {
  public static final Test$ MODULE$;

  public static {};
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class Test$
       3: invokespecial #12                 // Method "<init>":()V
       6: return

  public void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc2_w        #15                 // long 123456789l
       3: lstore_2
       4: fconst_1
       5: fstore        4
       7: lload_2
       8: l2d
       9: lload_2
      10: l2f
      11: f2d
      12: dsub
      13: d2f
      14: fstore        5
      16: lload_2
      17: l2f
      18: lload_2
      19: l2f
      20: fsub
      21: fstore        6
      23: return
}
```

Contrast:

1. `l2d`, followed by `l2f` and `f2d` in the first case; and `l2f` in the second case
2. `dsub`, followed by `d2f` in the first case; and `fsub` in the second case

---

### Credit

https://twitter.com/aphyr/status/831200481141805056.

Comment: I don't think numeric widening applies here. The behavior still seems wrong, though. What's actually happening is overload resolution for methods named `-` on the classes `Long` and `Float`, which should work as [stated in 12.2.1](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/12-the-scala-standard-library.html#numeric-value-types).

Comment: @HTNW I thought about that. However, isn't `Float` the operation type of `Long` and `Float`, not `Double` (with respect to "the operation type of S and T is the larger of the two types wrt ranking")?

Comment: @HTNW It would be clearer if you could spell out how overload resolution works in detail in this case. There's `def -(x: Float): Float` in `Long` and `def -(x: Long): Float` in `Float`. According to your comment, the first case picked `def -(x: Double): Double` instead of  `def -(x: Float): Float`, while the second case picked `def -(x: Long): Float` correctly. Why exactly?

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. I can only point out 1) the "numeric widening" rule in the standard does not apply here, period 2) there may or may not be "numeric widening" as an operation happening at runtime, which may or may not be legitimate 3) the correct rule to refer to is 12.2.1 for how the `-` methods are supposed to work 4) the overload resolution should be trivial 5) if you pass `-Ytyper-debug` the first case does not pick `def -(x: Double): Double`, and that doesn't make sense, anyway, as you get a `Float`. My guess is a compiler bug makes the `Float` overload incorrect.

Comment: @HTNW I guess how overload resolution works in this case is not trivial to me. That's why I asked for clarification. I tried `-Ytyper-debug` but I couldn't tell which overload version of `-` method was picked (in either case). Could you perhaps point it out to me?

Comment: The method is overloaded. Therefore, the argument must be typed without an expected type. The argument's type is thus decided purely from the expression itself. The following overload resolution is trivial; pick the overload with the matching argument type. In `-Ytyper-debug`, the resolution isn't explicitly stated, but is there. You see `-` getting typed as being overloaded (`Ty1 <and> Ty2 <and> ...`). Then you see the argument getting typed, and then you see the whole `l - r` expression getting typed. The type of the argument + the type of the expression demonstrate the chosen overload.

Comment: You can show this issue with just `x - x.toFloat` vs `x.toFloat - x`

Comment: @Tim, you're right and I've incorporated this into my answer. If you follow the Twitter reference link, you'll see that the example was originally used to demonstrate that the `else` branch forces an implicit lossy widening conversion of `x` from `Long` to `Float`. But that was just one of the issue, the other one was the compile bug. (Without the compiler bug, the rules to determine the expected type and the implicit conversions involved for Scala if expressions are similar to those for Java conditional expressions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

This is a bug in the Scala compiler (nsc).

I have noticed that the behavior of this program has changed in Scala v2.13.x. The old behavior is still the same in v2.12.x, up until v2.12.15. ([My PR](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/9751) has been merged to v2.12.16.)

Old behavior: `a` is `-3.0: Float` and `b` is `0.0: Float`.

New behavior: `a` is `0.0: Float` and `b` is `0.0: Float`.

Using `git bisect`, I've found that there was [a bug report regarding the same issue](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11253). The bug was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/f8699287d1ce4e238ae59dfd1bebb213af8daf8d), in [this PR](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/7435), and merged into v2.12.x branch.

Note that byte 8 `l2d`, and byte 11 `f2d` in the old bytecode are replaced by byte 8 `l2f`, and byte 11 `fsub` in the new one. Besides, byte 12 `dsub` and byte 13 `d2f` in the old one is missing in the new one.

Also note that bytes 7-12 (compute and set `a`) are identical to bytes 14-19 (compute and set `b`) (except for the destination of the `fstore` instructions) in the new one, as expected of the correct behavior.

## Overloading Resolution for `x.-(x.toFloat())`

Refer to [Section 6.26.3 - Overloading Resolution of the Scala Language Specification v2.12](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#overloading-resolution). There were some changes to the specs to support higher-order function parameter type inference in v2.13, but the rules regarding parameterized methods stay mostly the same.

`val a = x - (if (true) { x } else { y })` is equivalent to `val a: Float = x.-(x.toFloat());`. (See section Debug below.)

> Let A be the set of members referenced by e.

`A = {Long#-(Double): Double, Long#-(Float): Float, Long#-(Long): Long, Long#-(Int): Long, Long#-(Char): Long, Long#-(Short): Long, Long#-(Byte): Long}`

> Let B be the set of alternatives in A that are applicable to expressions (e1,…,en) of types (shape(e1),…,shape(en)).

Here the expressions are `(e1)` of type `(Nothing)`, hence `B = A`.

> Otherwise, let S1,…,Sm be the list of types obtained by typing each argument as follows.
> All other arguments are typed with an undefined expected type.

Here the expressions are `(e1)` of type `(Float)`.

> Otherwise, let CC be the set of applicable alternatives which don't employ any default argument in the application to e1,…,em.

`CC = {Long#-(Float): Float (1), Long#-(Double): Double (2)}`

Note that 1 is more specific than 2 because 1 is as specific as 2 but not the other way around.

Hence `Long#-(Float): Float` is the chosen alternative. This is comfirmed by `-Ytyper-debug` output. However, it doesn't state the chosen alternative explicitly.

## Debug

Scala generates source code for numeric value types that doesn't contain the implementation of most methods, e.g., [Long](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Long.scala). The actual implementation, e.g., for `Long#-` methods, are [generated at compile time](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/jvm/BCodeBodyBuilder.scala#L118). Since `-` is a (primitive arithmetic) binary operation, the result type of `lhs - rhs` is the operation type of `lhs` and `rhs`, which is computed by `BTypes#maxType`, which [for primitive types returns the result of `PrimitiveBType#maxValueType`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/jvm/BTypes.scala#L152) which had [the bug in Scala versions prior to v2.13.x](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.14/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/jvm/BTypes.scala#L300).

The code that is passed to Scala compiler (`scalac -print Test.scala`):

```
package <empty> {
  object Test extends Object {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val x: Long = 123456789L;
      val y: Float = 1.0;
      val a: Float = x.-(x.toFloat());
      val b: Float = x.toFloat().-(x);
      ()
    };
    def <init>(): Test.type = {
      Test.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

In the old bytecode for `val a: Float = x.-(x.toFloat());`:

- As part of [`genArithmeticOp(tree: Tree, code: Int)`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.14/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/jvm/BCodeBodyBuilder.scala#L104):

  - `tree` = `Trees.Apply(fun = Trees.Select(qualifier = "x", name = "$minus"), args = List(Trees.Apply(fun = Trees.Select(qualifier = "x", name = "toFloat"))))`
  - `code` = `ScalaPrimitives#SUB`
  - `larg` = `Trees.Select(qualifier = "x", name = "$minus")`
  - `rarg` = `Trees.Apply(fun = Trees.Select(qualifier = "x", name = "toFloat"))`
  - `tpeTK(larg)` = `BTypes.LONG`
  - `tpeTK(rarg)` = `BTypes.FLOAT`
  - `resKind` = `BTypes.LONG.maxType(BTypes.FLOAT)` = `BTypes.DOUBLE`
  - As part of [`genLoad(larg, resKind)`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.14/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/jvm/BCodeBodyBuilder.scala#L134):

    - byte 7 `lload_2` is generated by [`locals.load(x)`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.14/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/jvm/BCodeBodyBuilder.scala#L361)
    - byte 8 `l2d` is generated by adapt [`adapt(BTypes.LONG, BTypes.DOUBLE)`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.14/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/jvm/BCodeBodyBuilder.scala#L396)
  - As part of [`genLoad(rarg, if (isShiftOp) INT else resKind)`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.14/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/jvm/BCodeBodyBuilder.scala#L135):

    - As part of [`generatedType = genApply(app, expectedType)`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.14/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/jvm/BCodeBodyBuilder.scala#L303):

      - `expectedType` = `BTypes.DOUBLE`
      - As part of [`genLoad(x)`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.14/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/jvm/BCodeBodyBuilder.scala#L245):

        - byte 9 `lload_2` is generated by [`locals.load(x)`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.14/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/jvm/BCodeBodyBuilder.scala#L361)
      - byte 10 `l2f` is generated by [`genCoercion(ScalaPrimitives#L2F)`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.14/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/jvm/BCodeBodyBuilder.scala#L247)
      - byte 11 `f2d` is generated by [`adapt(BTypes.FLOAT, BTypes.DOUBLE)`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.14/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/jvm/BCodeBodyBuilder.scala#L396)
      - byte 12 `dsub` is generated by [`case SUB => bc sub resKind`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.14/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/jvm/BCodeBodyBuilder.scala#L139)
  - byte 13 `d2f` is generated by adapt [`adapt(BTypes.DOUBLE, BTypes.FLOAT)`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.14/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/backend/jvm/BCodeBodyBuilder.scala#L396)

## Bytecode

Bytecode for Scala v2.12.14 (old behavior - almost identical to that in the question):

```
$ javap -c 'Test$.class'
Compiled from "Test.scala"
public final class Test$ {
  public static Test$ MODULE$;

  public static {};
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class Test$
       3: invokespecial #12                 // Method "<init>":()V
       6: return

  public void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc2_w        #16                 // long 123456789l
       3: lstore_2
       4: fconst_1
       5: fstore        4
       7: lload_2
       8: l2d
       9: lload_2
      10: l2f
      11: f2d
      12: dsub
      13: d2f
      14: fstore        5
      16: lload_2
      17: l2f
      18: lload_2
      19: l2f
      20: fsub
      21: fstore        6
      23: return
}
```

Bytecode for Scala v2.13.0 (new behavior):

```
$ javap -c 'Test$.class'
Compiled from "Test.scala"
public final class Test$ {
  public static final Test$ MODULE$;

  public static {};
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class Test$
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #12                 // Method "<init>":()V
       7: putstatic     #14                 // Field MODULE$:LTest$;
      10: return

  public void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc2_w        #18                 // long 123456789l
       3: lstore_2
       4: fconst_1
       5: fstore        4
       7: lload_2
       8: l2f
       9: lload_2
      10: l2f
      11: fsub
      12: fstore        5
      14: lload_2
      15: l2f
      16: lload_2
      17: l2f
      18: fsub
      19: fstore        6
      21: return
}
```